# Formulario que se repita

Tags: php, html5, array, formularios, php5

Buen día a todo aquella persona que ve esta pregunta.
Quiero saber como puedo crear un formulario que se repita 5 veces y así mismo guardar esos 5 datos ingresados en un array.

Agradezco mucho a las que deseen ayudarme. :D

Comment: Cuando dices que se repita cinco veces a qué te refieres exactamente? Que el usuario rellene un formulario, lo mande y luego cargue otro así hats 5 veces?

Comment: Lo que necesito es que el formulario se repita 5 veces automaticamente luego de cada registro para asi ingresar 5 registros distintos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una versión con JQuery. también se puede hacer con AJAX o con puro PHP recargando cada página.

**Ejemplo con JQuery:**

Este es con un formulario sencillo, me imagino que necesitarás con un formulario más complejo pero la mecánica es la misma.

Utiliza el localstorge para almacenar los datos. Luego se puede gestionar en un php

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script></script>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){

        var veces = 4;
        var vuelta = 0;
        var formularios = {};

        localStorage.setItem('formularios', formularios);

        if(! localStorage.getItem('vuelta')) {
           localStorage.setItem('vuelta', 0);
        } else {
          vuelta =   localStorage.getItem('vuelta');
        }

        $('#vueltas').html("Vueltas= "+vuelta);

        $('#input_val').on('change', function(){
          $('#enviar').data('inputval', $(this).val());
        });

        $('#enviar').on('click', function(){

          if(parseInt(vuelta)<=parseInt(veces)) {

            var value_for = $(this).data('inputval');

            formularios[parseInt(vuelta)] = {'valor_input': value_for};

            localStorage.setItem('formularios', JSON.stringify(formularios));
            vuelta = parseInt(vuelta) +1;
            localStorage.setItem('veces', vuelta);
            $('#vueltas').html('Vueltas = '+vuelta);
          } else {

         // AQUÍ PUEDES HACER UN AJAX para gestionar esto en el servidor
// algo parecido a esto...
//$.ajax({
  //              url: "proces_mis_formularios.php",
    //            type: "POST",
    //            async: true,
    //            data: {
    //              formularios : formularios} ,
    //                  success: function(result) {
    //                     $('#vueltas').html('subidos formularios');
    // 
    //                  }
    //          });

            $('#for').html('Completados las '+veces+' N Vueltas= '+vuelta+' <br />'+localStorage.getItem('formularios') );
          }

        });

      });
    </script>
    <div id="vueltas">
      Vueltas = 0
    </div>
    <div id="for">


       <input type="text" name="nombre" value="" id="input_val" />
       <input type="submit" name="enviar" data-inputval="" id="enviar" value="enviar" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Por favor no respondas a preguntas que son tareas escolares y que no muestran avance o intento alguno por parte del OP, generalmente estas terminan cerradas, saludos.